# How to display several url links in message pane header?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I found only control for displaying one link. And when it is displaying it is empty, although the cursor looks like there is indeed the link underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns surprisingly simple. There can be used "grid" with row of several mail-urlfields. To do the link not empty the code

```
gMessageListeners.push({      
  onEndHeaders: function ()
  {          
      var elem3 = window.document.getElementById("my_header_value_Label3");
      elem3.headerValue= my_url;
  }
```

should be used.